# Startup.cs returns wrong environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

The Startup class contains

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

    Console.WriteLine($"{env.EnvironmentName.ToString()}");

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // For more details on using the user secret store see 
        // https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
        builder.AddUserSecrets();
    }

    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

but env.EnvironmentName.ToString() returns "Production".

I already setup my ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to "Development" in *launchSettings.json*

Comment: How do you start the project? `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` in project settings / launchSettings.json is only applied when starting from Visual Studio via F5 / Ctrl + F5. Starting it via dotnet or by any other means do not apply it. launchSattings.json is a pure VIsual Studio Mechanic

Comment: Is there anyway to set environment variables. I'm using visual studio code and dotnet core CLI for developement.

Comment: If you run it from command like, use your environments shell commands to set the environment variable (CommandLine, Powershell, bash, or whatever MacOS uses too)

Comment: already did this 'set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development' but still getting the wrong environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working using powershell command:

`$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"`

Answer (score 6):

This usually happens when you have setup environment in `web.config` too.

For example, if you have environment setup as `Production` in `launchSettings.json`-

```
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    },
```

And in `web.config`, if you have other environment `Staging`-

```
<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false">
  <environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Staging" />
  </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

In this case, you will get `Staging` when you are trying to read `env.EnvironmentName` in `startup.cs`

See if this helps.

Comment: Tried to put `<environmentVariables>` on web.config but still doesn't work. I'm using visual studio code and dotnet core CLI for developement.

Comment: If you not using VS2015 then you can set variable from command prompt like this- `set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` and then run `dotnet` commands.

Comment: already set it `set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`. Still getting the same result

Comment: I LOVE YOU! I spent FOREVER trying to figure this out... I am now bald

Comment: Outdated for asp.net core 2+: there is no more web.config

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful to some.

I was running locally against published files - that is not being run through visual studio F5. Setting the environment variable through the command line added it to the user environment variables which did not work.

What I had to do to get it to work was to add ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to the system environment variables. Then, after a reboot, it worked.

To get to environment variables:
Right-click on "This PC", then properties. Then Advanced system settings. Then finally click on button "environment variables". In the next pop up add to system variables.